# fetching the data dynamically from RestEnd points

Tags: javascript, frontend

I need to get the data from the REST endpoint and display it in some sort of filterable table, and update it if anything changes in the server.

(I dont want to get the data from static JSON file but everytime i make a GET call to rest end point i will get the data which is in json format)

are there any tutorials which can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To make a fetch call to an API endpoint, you would use JavaScripts built in fetch method. See below, I've built a fetch and even put in a dummy endpoint that returns actual JSON so you can see that it's working. Just replace the URL right after fetch with the the API endpoint you want to get JSON from...

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

The first .then makes sure the data is turned back into JSON and then passes the data down to the second .then. Inside that second .then is where you would handle the response by using (in this case) 'data' as the variable name. You can set those parameters to whatever you want to call them though. Finally, the .catch simply console logs the error message if the fetch is unsuccessful.

Here is a repl so you can see it working. Just hit run and you'll see the response: https://repl.it/repls/UnfoldedVibrantProcessor

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to continuously call the API endpoint to check for the data, updating the local dataset with each response. If the API is self-developed,restful and used solely for this example, then the data will be cached so it won't have a massive impact on performance/resources (if the data isn't changing rapidly).

Just shove the code you're using to call the endpoint e.g. Ajax calls within a setInterval() loop and it should work fine, updating the UI (table & contents) as you're re-performing the process over and over.

```
setInterval(function(){ 

   some AJAX call getting data ...
   ... use the AJAX response (data) to re-draw/update the table contents

}, 3000);
```

The process for getting what you want:

1. Implement continuous API caller (setInterval); initiated on document load.
2. Learn and Implement external API request e.g. AJAX
3. Parse data, create HTML using data to create a table structure or use external table library.
4. Use created HTML to dynamically modify the DOM using document.getElementById("#table you made in your html").innerHTML = ^#3